# Pass custom parameters in Laravel Validation with regex

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.6, error-messaging

Okay, I've got in a very difficult situation here and I think I'm either missing on something crucial that's already present or Laravel doesn't provide a way to achieve that as of right now. 
I'd like to specify a custom validation error message with a custom placeholder I'd like to replace in the message. The problem with that: I'm using the `regex` validation rule, about which [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex) explicitly points out, that it should be better passed in an array to avoid unwanted separator behavior. The situation is the following: I'd like to specify a global multilingual message for validating `name.regex`, which I've done so:

```
'custom' => [
    'name' => [
        'regex' => 'The :attribute must corespond to the given format: :format!'
    ]
]
```

As you can see, I've put a custom placeholder `:format` in that message, because for the `name` attribute of different classes I'm going to be matching different regular expressions. So I'd like to be able to input a custom human readable description of each given regex along the validation (as a parameter).
So I'm doin the following in my controller:

```
$input = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'regex:/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u']
    ]);
```

I've also got a `Validator::replacer()` method in my `AppServiceProvider.php` which should replace the `:format` placeholder in the message:

```
Validator::replacer('regex', function($message, $attr, $rule, $parameters){
        return str_replace(':format', "I would like to be able to somehow retrieve the custom format description here, but using \$parameters[] is not an option", $message);
    });
```

The problem with the `regex` validation rule is that I'm really not allowed to pass a parameter to it in the validator, like for example so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'regex:/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u,Thats my custom validator format description']
    ]);
```

because it completely messes up the regular expression (which should be that way). So I can't user $parameters[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex)$ in my `replacer()` to replace the placeholder. Furthermore it would be really inconvenient to have to pass a whole sentence as a comma-separated parameter of a validation rule. So that concept doesn't fit the needs.

The `:format` value will be dynamic and will severely vary throughout different classes' `name` fields requirements, so I really need that dynamic multilingual description to be set as a property of the current validator instance. I thought maybe the most convenient scenario would be the something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'regex:/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u', 'format:Current name requirements described here.']
    ]);
```

and Laravel somehow knows that `:format` should be replaced by the present rule somewhere in the messages of that instance. I thought about explicitly adding this additional parameter as a validation rule and later on manage it, but I'm really unable to achieve the cross-rule connection (in other words, to get the parameter of the new `format` rule and use it in the `regex` rule). 
I really don't know how to approach that issue and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm aware I could specify the whole message each time this way:

```
$input = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'regex:/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u']
    ],
[
    'name.regex' => 'My custom message here'
]);
```

but I don't want to have to input the whole message each time, because it might later on contain other placeholders (that might be global or so) in it and I want to use the multilingual base message provided via the `validator.php` files, so I really need to replace the `:format` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom rule:

```
php artisan make:rule CustomRegex
```

Then update the constructor to support both the regex and description of the format.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomRegex implements Rule
{
    /** @var string $attribute The attribute of we are validating. */
    public $attribute;

    /** @var string $description The description of the regex format. */
    public $description;

    /** @var string $regex The regex to validate. */
    public $regex;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param string $regex The regex to validate.
     * @param string $description The description of the regex format.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $regex, string $description)
    {
        $this->regex = $regex;
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $this->attribute = $attribute;

        return preg_match($this->regex, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return trans('validation.custom.name', [
            'attribute' => $this->attribute,
            'format' => $this->description
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then when you validate:

```
use App\Rules\CustomRegex;

request()->validate([
    'name' => [
        'required', new CustomRegex('/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u', 'The description of your format')
    ]
]);
```

Then the output message would look like this:

> The name must corespond to the given format: The description of your format!

Comment: Thought of it a brief moment after I woke up today, now I see you've mentioned the exact same thing! Thanks! I'd be happy if that gets added out of the box in next versions. I mean, just a little bit more detailed version of the `regex` rule, so that you can also pass parameters. It's not that much necessary, but it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way as i can figured out in Laravel 5.6 is to use closure:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, 
    [
        'name' => 
           [
             'required',
             function($attribute, $value, $fail) {

                 $regex = '/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}+$/u';

                 if (!preg_match($regex, $value)) {

                    return $fail('Your custom message with' .
                    $attribute . ' name and its value = ' . $value);
                 }
             },
           ]
    ]);
```

Inside this closure you can add whatever you want. You can calculate readable format form and adds it to error message.

Comment: Check out my last P.S. This kind of functionality (setting the current [b]whole[/b] error message) is already available via the third argument of the `Validator::make()` function (`$messages`). The problem is I really don't want to rewrite the whole messages each time, but to rather just be able to input that single parameter of my own [b]and[/b] still use the message base, specified in the `validator.php` translation file.